# How do I append a column from one dataframe to another dataframe in power query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

How do I append a column from one dataframe to another dataframe in power query?

- note

  - The num of rows are the same.
- note

  - (I cannot do this in Python, as that will cause the lose of binary files.)
  - (why I do such following ex -- this is just a dummy example)
  - (I dont have any id as join column)
  - (when I tried to convert that to a List then append, the same happens...)
- ambiguity

  - for `append` a column, I mean `merge/join` in power query terminology. (see eg below)

eg:

- given

  ```
  | Content              | Name           | Extension  | Date accessed       | Date modified       | Date created        | Attributes | Folder Path                                                              |
  |----------------------|----------------|------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  | Binary.FromText(...) | .gitignore     | .gitignore | 2023/12/12 21:14:57 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | [Record]   | G:\wsp\dataset\COVID-19\csse_covid_19_data\csse_covid_19_daily_reports\  |
  | Binary.FromText(...) | 01-01-2021.csv | .csv       | 2023/12/12 22:16:12 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | [Record]   | G:\wsp\dataset\COVID-19\csse_covid_19_data\csse_covid_19_daily_reports\  |
  | Binary.FromText(...) | 01-01-2022.csv | .csv       | 2023/12/12 22:19:20 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | [Record]   | G:\wsp\dataset\COVID-19\csse_covid_19_data\csse_covid_19_daily_reports\  |
  | Binary.FromText(...) | 01-01-2023.csv | .csv       | 2023/12/12 22:19:20 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | [Record]   | G:\wsp\dataset\COVID-19\csse_covid_19_data\csse_covid_19_daily_reports\  |
  ```
- expected

  ```
  | Content              | Name           | Extension  | Date accessed       | Date modified       | Date created        | Attributes | Folder Path                                                              | filterout     |
  |----------------------|----------------|------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|
  | Binary.FromText(...) | .gitignore     | .gitignore | 2023/12/12 21:14:57 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | [Record]   | G:\wsp\dataset\COVID-19\csse_covid_19_data\csse_covid_19_daily_reports\  | AppendedData1 |
  | Binary.FromText(...) | 01-01-2021.csv | .csv       | 2023/12/12 22:16:12 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | [Record]   | G:\wsp\dataset\COVID-19\csse_covid_19_data\csse_covid_19_daily_reports\  | AppendedData1 |
  | Binary.FromText(...) | 01-01-2022.csv | .csv       | 2023/12/12 22:19:20 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | [Record]   | G:\wsp\dataset\COVID-19\csse_covid_19_data\csse_covid_19_daily_reports\  | AppendedData1 |
  | Binary.FromText(...) | 01-01-2023.csv | .csv       | 2023/12/12 22:19:20 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | 2023/12/12 15:24:49 | [Record]   | G:\wsp\dataset\COVID-19\csse_covid_19_data\csse_covid_19_daily_reports\  | AppendedData1 |
  ```
- attempt fail

  ```
  let
      Source = Folder.Files("G:\wsp\dataset\COVID-19\csse_covid_19_data\csse_covid_19_daily_reports"),
      Source2 = Folder.Files("G:\wsp\dataset\COVID-19\csse_covid_19_data\csse_covid_19_daily_reports"),
      // #"appendedTable" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "filterout", each [Name]) // now "filterout" each contains a String of name << correct
      #"appendedTable" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "filterout", each Source2[Name]) //  now "filterout" each contains a List of names << wrong
  in
      appendedTable
  ```

  - (I dont understand why after the append, each row contains a List? 
        `#"appendedTable" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "filterout", each Source2[Name]) //  now "filterout" each contains a List of names << wrong`)

Comment: Update your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77651454/edit) with a [markdown table](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) of the source and another one for what you need it to be. What's your definition of "append a column"?

Comment: @SamNseir Updated the table, though I dont think it helps -- the que just a simple idea. \ 
For the reason of "appending a column", I think its very common and general, eg: just add some random data for debugging purpose.

Comment: "Append" in PowerQuery means "union" hence my asking what your definition is. I'm not understanding what you are wanting. You want to add a column to your table, what should this column have? Your line is "add a column, and for each row, add the whole column of another table". This of course will give you a list. Without a common id of the two tables you cannot **MERGE**, and I think `MERGE` (or join) is what you are wanting.

Comment: @SamNseir I did doubt the use of "append" vs "merge", I searched for them. \
- But didnt found any function with "merge" naming. \
- And the try of `#"appendedTable" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "filterout", each [Name])` was the only thing it worked -- when in the same dataframe (so, made me confused). \
- Did fnd "join". I went with `sourceIndexed = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),` & `Table.Join(` did work. \
But I dont want to append another Index Column due to complexity or performance issue. Its sad that >"Without a common id of the two tables you cannot MERGE".

Comment: @SamNseir (btw, just found that: "What's your definition of "append a column"?" I misread that as "What's your reason of "append a column"?")

Comment: Your use case isn't clear. It seems like you simply want to "move/copy" a column from one table to another table, regardless of the order of the rows - is that it?

Comment: @SamNseir Yes, regardless of the order (-- just natural index order of the list). \
The answer post below solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append column **Name** from table **Source2** to **Source**

```
 Append = Table.FromColumns ( Table.ToColumns(Source) & {Source2[Name]},Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"Name"} )
```

Comment: Yes it worked, it just you had an extra `)` somewhere. \
For case in que: `#"appendedTable" = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source) & {Source2[Name]}, Table.ColumnNames(Source) & {"Name_filterout"})`

Comment: my bad sorry, will fix in original. Thanks for pointing out